# checkUsage cannot check against self assignment

Tags: r

I guess the following code checking

```
library(codetools)

f_tmp <- function(x) {
  y <- y
  x
}

checkUsage(f_tmp)
```

would print something like this:

```
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘y’
```

but instead it prints nothing. Is it a bug of codetools or not belonging to usage error in codetools?